# Changing shapes and colors of blocks also redirecting arrows properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-trees

I would like to have a flow chart as shown below.
[image]

I have my initial latex code below but I am having trouble changing shapes, colors of blocks and redirecting arrows properly. Someone, please help. Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
    %\pagestyle{empty}%
    %\noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance =0.8cm, auto]
    % Define block styles
    \tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
            text width=15em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
        line/.style={draw, -latex'}}
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (inputdata) {Read input data};
    \node [block, below=of inputdata] (initialchecks) {Initial checks and calculation of means and standard deviations};
    \node [block,below=of initialchecks] (stage1) {Stage 1:SNHT applied on stepped overlapping windows
    };
    \node [block,below=of stage1] (stage2) {Stage 2:SNHT applied on the whole series
    };
    \node [block,below=of stage2] (stage3) {Stage 3:In-filling of all missing data
    };
    \node [block, below =of stage3] (writehomo) {Write homogeneous files, graphics and other outputs};
    \node [block, below right=of inputdata] (normalize) {Normalize series with their means and standard devaitions};
    \node [block, below= of normalize] (estimate) {Estimate all series from their neighbours and normalize
    };
    \node [block,below= of estimate] (anomalies) {Compute anomalies(observed - estimated) and remove outliers};
    \node [block, below=of anomalies] (infill) {In-fill missing data and compute new means and standard deviations};
    \node [block, below=of infill] (yesno) {Did any means change? };
    ;
    \node [block, right=of normalize] (ifstage3) {If stage 3 return };
    \node [block, below=of ifstage3 ] (compute) {Compute SNHT of all series };
    ;
    \node [block, below=of compute] (max) {If maximum SNHT or lower than threshold return};
    ;
    \node [block, below=of max] (split) {Split series with higher SNHT break points};
    ;
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (inputdata) -- (initialchecks);
    \path [line] (initialchecks) -- (stage1);
    \path [line] (stage1) -- (stage2);
    \path [line] (stage2) -- (stage3);
    \path [line] (stage3) -- (writehomo);
    \path [line] (stage1) -- (normalize);
    \path [line] (normalize) -- (estimate);
    \path [line] (estimate) -- (anomalies);
    \path [line] (anomalies) -- (infill);
    \path [line] (infill) -- (yesno);
    \path [line] (yesno) -- (ifstage3);
    \path [line] (ifstage3) -- (compute);
    \path [line] (compute) -- (max);
    \path [line] (max) -- (split);
    \path [line] (split) -- (normalize);
    \path [line] (stage2) -- (normalize);
    \path [line] (yesno) -- (normalize);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

With use of `tikz` libraries `chains` and its macro `join` I significantly shorten your code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{suspend join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 4mm and 30mm,
      start chain = A going below,
      base/.style = {draw, text width=32mm, minimum height=8mm,
                     font=\small\sffamily, align=center, on chain=A, join=by -Stealth},
 startstop/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=red!30},
   process/.style = {base, rectangle, fill=#1},
        io/.style = {base, trapezium, trapezium stretches,
                     trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                     fill=blue!30},
  decision/.style = {base, text width=24mm, diamond, aspect=1.2,
                     fill=#1, inner xsep=0pt},
decision/.default = yellow!30,
every path/.style = {draw, -Stealth},
                    ]
 % Place nodes
    \begin{scope}[process/.default = blue!20]
\node [io]      {Read input data};  % A-1
\node [process] {Initial checks and calculation of means and standard deviations};
\node [process] {Stage 1: SNHT applied on stepped overlapping windows};
\node [process] {Stage 2: SNHT applied on the whole series};
\node [process] {Stage 3: In-filling of all missing data};
\node [process] {Write homogeneous files, graphics and other outputs};  % A-6
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[process/.default = yellow!20]
\node [process, suspend join,
       below right=of A-1]  {Normalize series with their means and standard devaitions}; % A-7
\node [process]     {Estimate all series from their neighbours and normalize};
\node [process]     {Compute anomalies(observed - estimated) and remove outliers};
\node [process]     {In-fill missing data and compute new means and standard deviations};
\node [decision]    {Did any means change?};
\node [decision, suspend join,
       right=22mm of A-8]  {If stage 3 return };     % A-12
\node [process]     {Compute SNHT of all series };
\node [decision]    {If max. SNHT or lower than threshold return};
\node [process]     {Split series with higher SNHT break points};   % A-15
    \end{scope}
% Draw edges
\path   (A-3.east)  -- ++ (0.3,0) |- ([yshift= 3mm] A-7);
\path   (A-4.east)  -- ++ (0.4,0) |- ([yshift= 1mm] A-7);
\path   (A-5.east)  -- ++ (0.5,0) |- ([yshift=-1mm] A-7);
%
\path   (A-11.west) -- ++ (-0.6,0) node[above right] {Yes} |- ([yshift=-3mm] A-7);
%
\path   (A-11.east) -- ++ ( 0.6,0) node[above  left] {No} |- (A-12);
%
\path   (A-15.east) -- ++ (1,0) |- (A-7);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Connection between nodes are drawn by macro `join`. They are interrupted between each branch with style `suspend join` Branches as well nodes between branches are drawn separately. They use orthogonal coordinates `|-` (first drawn vertically than horizontally) as for example

```
\path   (A-15.east) -- ++ (1,0) |- (A-7);
```

For node names are used names defined by use of `chains` library from `A-1` to `A-15`.

Comment: This is perfect! Many thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not super efficient, but a start ...

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance =0.8cm, auto]
  % Define block styles
  \tikzset{
    block/.style={draw, text width=15em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
    bblock/.style={block, fill=blue!20},
    yblock/.style={block, fill=yellow!20},
    line/.style={draw, -latex'},
    my trapezium/.style={trapezium, text width=12.5em, trapezium stretches, trapezium left angle=60, trapezium right angle=120},
    my diamond/.style={diamond, aspect=1.5, text width=10em}
  }
  % Place nodes
  \node [bblock, my trapezium] (inputdata) {Read input data};
  \node [bblock, below=of inputdata] (initialchecks) {Initial checks and calculation of means and standard deviations};
  \node [bblock,below=of initialchecks] (stage1) {Stage 1:SNHT applied on stepped overlapping windows
  };
  \node [bblock,below=of stage1] (stage2) {Stage 2:SNHT applied on the whole series
  };
  \node [bblock,below=of stage2] (stage3) {Stage 3:In-filling of all missing data
  };
  \node [bblock, below =of stage3, my trapezium] (writehomo) {Write homogeneous files, graphics and other outputs};
  \node [yblock, right=of inputdata] (normalize) {Normalize series with their means and standard devaitions};
  \node [yblock, below= of normalize] (estimate) {Estimate all series from their neighbours and normalize
  };
  \node [yblock,below= of estimate] (anomalies) {Compute anomalies(observed - estimated) and remove outliers};
  \node [yblock, below=of anomalies] (infill) {In-fill missing data and compute new means and standard deviations};
  \node [yblock, below=of infill, my diamond, text width=7.5em] (yesno) {Did any means change? };
  ;
  \node [yblock, right=75pt of normalize.south east, my diamond, anchor=north west, text width=5em] (ifstage3) {If stage 3 return };
  \node [yblock, below=of ifstage3 ] (compute) {Compute SNHT of all series };
  ;
  \node [yblock, below=of compute, my diamond] (max) {If maximum SNHT or lower than threshold return};
  ;
  \node [yblock, below=of max] (split) {Split series with higher SNHT break points};
  ;
  % Draw edges
  \path [line] (inputdata) -- (initialchecks);
  \path [line] (initialchecks) -- (stage1);
  \path [line] (stage1) -- (stage2);
  \path [line] (stage2) -- (stage3);
  \path [line] (stage3) -- (writehomo);
  \path [line] (stage1.east) -- +(2.5pt,0) |- ([yshift=5pt]normalize);
  \path [line] (normalize) -- (estimate);
  \path [line] (estimate) -- (anomalies);
  \path [line] (anomalies) -- (infill);
  \path [line] (infill) -- (yesno);
  \path [line] (yesno.east) -- +(22pt,0) node [midway,above] {No} |-  (ifstage3);
  \path [line] (ifstage3) -- (compute);
  \path [line] (compute) -- (max);
  \path [line] (max) -- (split);
  \path [line] (split.east) -- +(5pt,0) |- (normalize);
  \path [line] (stage2.east) -- +(5pt,0) |- (normalize);
  \path [line] (stage3.east) -- +(7.5pt,0) |- ([yshift=-5pt]normalize);
  \path [line] (yesno.west) -- +(-21pt,0) node [midway,above] {Yes} |- ([yshift=-7.5pt]normalize);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: flowchart]

You could use the `chains` library to make this easier, especially if you have several to do. It seems to be considered deprecated by the `graphs` stuff, but isn't really replaced by that and often does the job.